# Core data and iCloud sync not working in live App

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

Just finished and app that uses core data and iCloud sync. The app is just working fine while testing on the simulator and on devices: adding text and images to the persistent store without problems, all data is restored and all devices: on the simulator and real iPhones. I did a lot of tests like deleting the App from the phone and simulators and the data persists every time I reinstall/run the App.

Now the App is "live" in the App store but the data is not syncing between devices. I have installed on two iPhones using the same Apple username/ID, added records on both devices and the data is not restored or duplicated on each phone as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get any errors while accessing iCloud?

Comment: No. Both phones have on on using iCloud, and both phones shows some used iCloud space (> 2 MG)

Comment: If both phones show used iCloud space, don' they use the same (probably public) iCloud space for sync?

Comment: It should use the same space. Not sure what’s happening. Reinstalling from Xcode and running the simulators, works as expected but no on the ‘live’ App.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner look at the solution bellow. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Nicoli Hi, running into the same issue, but at the TestFlight stage. Did the "Deploy Schema to Production" tip in the Dev environment, to no avail. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did not know that, but once the App is approved, we need to deploy the schema to production, otherwise Cloudkit will not go live.

To do so, go to icloud.developer.apple.com, on your dashboard, click on the gear icon and "Deploy Schema to Production".

[image]

Hope this helps others with the same dilema ;)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment` key in your entitlements file to "Production".

Comment: thanks for your Answer to this Question. However, in my .entitlements file, I find only this entry: APS Environment set to development. Is this the same?

Comment: No, it's not the same. Create a new line in your entitlements file and name it com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment and set it to String and provide it with a "Production" or "Development" value, depending on how you want to build your app project.

Comment: is this still actual in iOS 15? I mean I've production databases on my testflight everything is syncing fine without setting anything in entitlements file

Comment: You have to explicitly point your app to the right environment. Simply deploying the development scheme to production is not enough. Your app still uses the development scheme, even after you deploy your development scheme to production. Until you add the right key/value pair to your entitlements file, your app will not use the right environment. Things will work for development, testflight and review, but will stop working when your app is released to the appstore.